# es6 iterator in codepen sandbox

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i run this code:

```
function* quips(name) {
  yield "hello " + name + "!";
  yield "i hope you are enjoying the blog posts";
  if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith("x")) {
    yield "hey, it's cool how your name starts with an X, " + name;
  }
  yield "see you later!";
  yield* quips(name)
}

var meow_iter = quips("Xingu");

showCat();
```

and catch some referenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Louy sorry. I just copy-paste code from here http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/demos/meow.html, but error occurs before calling `showCat`. You may sure http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Veveey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the `showCat` part. It's working otherwise.

Here's a demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVeVao?editors=001

(check browser console)

If it still doesn't work for you, then your browser doesn't support es6 generators. Adding a preprocessor (like babel) should make it work. Go to Settings->JS->Preprocessor in codepen.